# how to add action after login in with FBLoginButton?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

following is my code:

FBLoginButton *  button = [[[FBLoginButton alloc]  init] autorelease];

[button touchUpInside];

how to add action after press login in button with FBLoginButton?  could you give a hand? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make bot an -(IBAction) method wich you should link with the button on touched up inside. When the button is pressed the method will be called.